# jQuery on click not returning any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

What I am trying to do is to get all inputs and data when someone click the submit button.

My code HTML is this:

```
<form id="form" action="index.php" method="POST" class="register" name="Register">
    <label>Patient Name:</label>
    <input id="pname" name="pname" placeholder="John Doe" type="text" data-role="justText" value=""><br><br>
    <label>Phone Number:</label>
    <input id="ptel" type="tel" name="ptel" value=""><br><br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input id="pemail" placeholder="example@gmail.com" type="email" value=""><br><br>
    <button id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" name="register">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

Don't know if it's the best use the button or input tag for submit the form. And the jQuery to handle what I am trying to do is this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
        hello: function () {

            submitbutton = $(this).find('button').attr('id');
            $inputs = $(this).find('input');

            knowInputs = function() {
                $inputs.each(function () {
                    console.log( $(this).attr('name') );
                });
            }

            $('#'+submitbutton).on('click', function () {
                knowInputs();

            })
            return this;
        }
    });
```

So, I put the form ID and init the function like this:

```
$(#form).hello();
```

P.D.: If I put the code knowInputs outside the on(click), it seems to work fine. My problem is when I am trying to gather all when clicking the submit button.

Any help shall be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just get the form data in the form’s submit event? There is no need to extend JQuery for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms have a native Javascript event, `submit`. jQuery also has a function, `$.serialize` which will turn a form into an encoded URL string, which is probably the most standard format you'd want it in. You can easily convert this into JSON or a JS Object.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return $(this).serialize();
});
```

Comment: That help me a lot. I need to know some attributes of the input as well just like "type" and "name" but, with the approach you gave me, helped me a lot. Thanks, @Bricky